# Spring websocket MissingSessionUserException: No "user" header in message

Tags: backbone.js, websocket, stomp, spring-websocket

I have problem when I try to send message from client to server on Spring websocket.
I have configuration Websocket on server and create @Message on controller.
I send data from client via javascript.
It just work sometimes, but sometimes it fail and throw message on server: **MissingSessionUserException: No "user" header in message**

Here're my WebsocketConfig:

```
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/connectsocket").withSockJS();
    }
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/");
    }
}
```

Here're my MessageController:

```
@RestController
public class MessageController {

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    @MessageMapping("/websocket/message")
    public synchronized void message(Message<Object> messageObj, 
        WebMessage message, Principal principal) throws Exception {
        if (principal != null) {
            String name = principal.getName();
            template.convertAndSendToUser(name, "/topic/dynamic", new MessagePojo("stage", "value", "message"));
        }
    }
}
```

Here're my Javascript-backbonejs code:

```
app.Models.WebsocketModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    fetchData : function() {
        console.log("WebsocketModel: fetchData");
        var socket = new SockJS(url + "/connectsocket");
        var client = Stomp.over(socket);

        var onConnect = function(frame) {
            console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
            client.subscribe("/user/topic/dynamic", function(data) {
                var jsonBody = JSON.parse(data.body);
                console.log(jsonBody);
            });
        };

        client.connect({}, onConnect);

        setInterval(function() {
            client.send("/websocket/message", {}, JSON.stringify({
                "message" : "Hello world!!!",
                "toUser" : "Someone"
            }));
        }, 10000);
    }
});
```

Here're my server error log:

> [2016 Apr 14 - 02:13:19] ERROR:
>   [org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler]
>   - Unhandled exception org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.MissingSessionUserException:
>   No "user" header in message   at
>   org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.PrincipalMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PrincipalMethodArgumentResolver.java:42)
>     at
>   org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
>     at
>   org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:108)
>     at
>   org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:490)
>     at
>   org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.java:497)
>     at
>   org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:451)
>     at
>   org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:389)
>     at
>   org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel$SendTask.run(ExecutorSubscribableChannel.java:135)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to subscribe to a [user destination](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-user-destination) so the user must be authenticated.

If that is an anonymous user who want to subscribe to the topic, [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21317988/1535679) will help.

You'll have to assign an anonymous identify to the user and there are two options:

1. Configure a sub-class of `DefaultHandshakeHandler` that overrides `determineUser` and assigns some kind of identity to every WebSocketSession.
2. The WebSocket session will fall back on the value returned from `HttpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal` on the handshake HTTP request. You could have a servlet Filter wrap the HttpServletRequest and decide what to return from that method. Or if you're using Spring Security which has the AnonymousAuthenticationFilter, override its `createAuthentication` method.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Stanley.

I have solved my issues a long times ago and it's the same with you suggestion. It will be helpful for other one like me.

In the past, I checked header on network before client send to server, then I see missing user authentication. After that I just add user authentication before client send to server and it works fine.